# In the real number system, the equation $\sqrt{x+3-4\sqrt{x-1}}+\sqrt{x+8-6\sqrt{x-1}}=1$ has how many solutions

Tags: functions

I did what I was supposed to do, squared it many times. It’s too long to type out, but in the end, the RHS and LHS cancelled each other out, indicating that it doesn’t depend on $x$. So are there infinitely many solutions, or no solutions? I think it’s the latter, but I would like to get it confirmed.

Comment: Both terms on the LHS tend to infinity, so it can't be true for all (sufficiently large) $x$. I think your plus sign should be a minus.

Comment: With a minus sign, the equation holds as long as $\sqrt{x-1}\ge 4$, i.e. $x\ge 10$.

Comment: @TonyK it’s definitely plus

Comment: Well then it's definitely invalid for large $x$. The LHS is approximately $2\sqrt x$ when $x$ is large.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Let $\sqrt{x-1}=y$

For real solution, we need $x-1\ge0,$  consequently $y\ge0$

$$\sqrt{x+3-4\sqrt{x-1}}=\sqrt{y^2+1+3-4y}=\sqrt{(y-2)^2}=|y-2|=\begin{cases}y-2 &\mbox{if } y-2\ge0 \\
-(y-2) & \mbox{if } y-2<0 \end{cases}$$

Similarly,$$\sqrt{x+8-6\sqrt{x-1}}=|y-3|$$

So,we need to consider  the following three cases separately:

$y<2,  2\le y<3, y\ge3$

Comment: So I solved $|y-2|+|y-3|=1$ and got y as 3 and 2. Is that right? That would imply that the equation has two distinct solutions

Comment: @Aditya: For $2\le y\le 3$, we have $|y-2|+|y-3|=(y-2)+(3-y)=1$.

Comment: @Aditya, Have you considered all the three cases as suggested ?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I think I have. Please let me know if I missed. For what Mathlove said, y gets cancelled, so the case remains invalid

Comment: @Aditya,  Clearly any  $y,2\le y\le 3$  will satisfy the required equation. Please share your steps

Comment: No you are right. Since there are infinitely many real numbers between 2,3 the solution will have infinite solution?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $x+3-4\sqrt{x-1} = (\sqrt{x-1}-2)^2, x+8-6\sqrt{x-1} = (\sqrt{x-1} - 3)^2$ . I hope you can finish it.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x=1+t^2$ for $t\ge 0$. Then $|t-2|+|t-3|=1$ and so we have infinitely many solutions for $2\le t\le3$.