# If the equation $|2-x|-|x+1|=k$ has exactly one solution, then number of integral values of k is

Tags: functions

Opening the moduli

$$2-x-x+1=k$$
$$3-2x=k$$
And 
$$2-x+x+1=k$$
$$k=3$$
And 
$$x-2+x+1=k$$
$$2x-1=k$$

I am not sure if I am doing this right, but solving the first and and third equation, I get k=1. Is that right? So there are 2 values for k.

I think this is wrong. Please let me know the right method to solve it.

Comment: The only way you can open the absolute value the way you did is if both $\;2-x\ge0\;$ and also $\;x+1\ge0\;$ , meaning: only for $\;-1\le x\le2\;$ . What about the rest of the possible real values?

Comment: @Aditya, why don't you follow https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3526905/in-the-real-number-system-the-equation-sqrtx3-4-sqrtx-1-sqrtx8-6-sqrt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is useful to notice
$$|2-x| = \begin{cases}
2-x & x \leq 2 \\
x-2 & x \geq 2,
\end{cases}
\qquad
|x+1| = \begin{cases}
-x-1 & x\leq -1 \\
x+1 & x\geq -1.
\end{cases} $$
Playing with the conditions (try it!), the function on the LHS, rewritten in piecewise form, becomes
$$f(x)=
\begin{cases}
3 & x \leq -1 \\
1-2x & x \in[-1 ,2] \\
-3 & x \geq 2.
\end{cases}
$$
Clearly $f(x) = \pm 3$ is true for uncountably many $x$, and $f(x) = \pm k$ with integer $k > 3$ has none. How many integer $k$'s are between $-3$ and $3$?

Comment: What about $1-2x$?

Comment: What is the value of $|2-x|$ for $x \geq -1$? What is the value of $|x+1|$ for $x \leq 2$? What about $f(x)$ when $x$ satisfies both conditions?

Answer (score 3):

> If $x\ge2$

$(x-2)-(x+1)=k$ i.e. $k=-3$ has infinitely many solutions.

> If $2>x> -1$

$(2-x)-(x+1)=k$ i.e. $k=1-2x$. Then, for $3>k> -3$, there is a unique solution.

> If $-1\ge x$

$(2-x)+(x+1)=k$ i.e. $k=3$ has infinitely many solutions.

Comment: How was $3>k>-3$ determined in the second case?

Comment: $k=1-2x$ and $x$ lies between $-1$ and $2$.